# Indexing into mapped type using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to index into a mapped type using a generic argument. Below is a minimum example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```js
  interface JsonApiObject {
    attributes: { [key: string]: any };
    id: string;
    type: string;
  }

  type Narrow<Union, Type> = Union extends { type: Type }
    ? Union
    : never;

  type Store<TStore extends JsonApiObject> = {
      [TModel in TStore as TModel['type']]: {
          [id: string]: TModel;
      };
  };

class TypedStore<TStore extends JsonApiObject> {
    constructor(private readonly store: Store<TStore>) { }

    getModel<T extends TStore['type']>(name: T, id: string): Narrow<TStore, T> {
        return this.store[name][id];
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that `return this.store[name][id]` is failing to compile with the following message

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.(7053)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Here's a TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjawBSBnA9uAggA6gDyARgFbTKTADeAUCCIpJLKKQK4yYBcdwANoBraAE9%20mNhADmAXX6JwY4AF8A3IyagAJpOngZmpsEhiC0fe0PG19LWYvAAcolixsAdwA8AVXCguAA0wAAq5tAAfMAAvMD%20geDA0AAeMOA6mAKOlmERdiAA-PEBuFr84NAAbnCaDvkAypDYsNDeoU0taKnpmRg4%20ERklNTRcQwmIIKhALLYOtAANmBJHc2twIhZs-NLggDkOftyCnRak0yCulaypzsLi7YmGlov9MiLW9sROp2t7X9umloBkslhcIQSBQqJBohMmMhcFJYJxqC0ABQEdhVFhoVqIHS4RYqKRdfiAgHrKIASgEqnsJhk0Egcwe7WSwNBYUBByOcki6PAiAAtrlQiFrsBkbJqfxXO4vJSuiFQnDzpNWpBOLAkpAABagTAAOlJrUEQtFciuOjkTzsqiAA) for the example

Comment: You're asking the compiler to do higher order type manipulation with generic conditional types, but it can't really do that.  (i.e., the compiler cannot see that `Store<S>[T][string]` is equivalent to `Narrow<S, T>`) Why not define `Store` in terms of `Narrow` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKyLoN)?  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining why the original method doesn't work and why this one does.  If it doesn't meet your needs, what am I missing?

Comment: I'd love a writeup, but the issue happens before the `Narrow<S, T>`. Shouldn't the compiler understand that `Store<S>[T]` is at least a `{ [id: string]: JsonApiObject }` based on the information provided? I understand needing to cast the whole thing `Store<S>[T][string]` to `Narrow<S, T>`, but it's failing before that

Comment: It sure looks like the compiler defers indexing into a generic remapped object so that it can't really "understand" anything much.  It would take extra processing to verify that `{[T in U as F<T>]: G<T>}[F<U>]` is assignable to `G<U>` (for covariant `F` and `G`), and most of the time such processing would be wasted.  I don't know if I can find an authoritative source for that, though.  Should I proceed, or do you want something else?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great, and really appreciate you taking the time to look into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the compiler *defers* evaluation of an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a [key-remapped mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  It doesn't spend extra processing time trying to synthesize a meaningful constraint for `Store<S>[T]`; it just sees it as an opaque type which might or might not have any given properties.  So `Store<S>[T][string]` is a type error, and things break.

See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47794#issuecomment-1038826688) in [microsoft/TypeScript#47794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47794) for an authoritative source:

> We consider an indexed access type `{ [P in K]: E }[X]` to be constrained to an instantiation of `E` where `P` is replaced with `X`. However, this simplification is correct only when the mapped type doesn't specify an `as` clause... **While it may be desirable to perform the constraint simplification for mapped types with `as` clauses, it isn't possible because we can't consistently construct a reverse mapping for the `as` clause (indeed, it may not even be a 1:1 mapping)**.

And also [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48626#issuecomment-1098168620) in [microsoft/TypeScript#48626](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48626):

> we can't generally simplify generic mapped types to instantiations of their template type when an `as` clause is present

---

So, what can be done instead? Since you're trying to get `Narrow<S, T>` from `Store<S>[T][string]`, maybe you should write `Store<S>` in terms of `Narrow` directly:

```
type Store<S extends JsonApiObject> = {
  [T in S['type']]: {
    [id: string]: Narrow<S, T>;
  };
};
```

This is just a regular [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) without an `as` clause.  Indexing into it gives us the constraint mentioned above... that is, `Store<S>[T] extends {[id: string]: Narrow<S, T>}`.  And then things just work:

```
getModel<T extends S['type']>(name: T, id: string): Narrow<S, T> {
  return this.store[name][id]; // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIGcD2ICCAHYAeQCMArCBMZAbwChlk4wwphiBXSdALhuQG0A1hACevdC1ABzALq84IEcgC+AbnrJgAE3GSQU9QzAi8EXa33rltWsdPIAcnChRMAdwA8AVQA0yACoAfMgAvMheyBAAHpAgWuh8dmYBKsgA-OHIvCAQAG7Q6rQA9ABUtiYoAMpgmFAQHpWRMRBxCRjY+ERkFGDBYXQM-P6aIMiNcAn+-ADkSdMycjQag9rm0ov+hipW6iVFNkljNXUNTbHxaFi4BCTklH1Lg8OgYzNzC7wDDAKryBIWsl4Thc7gafiCWzUtChtAQABsJpMKlpqrV6o1ouc2ldOrcesEvghsP92JRagAKPCsXJMFB1OBabBwpQSNG8VEnSqBACUfGsGikEDAAFlMFoIHCPMNMS0LpU3hV5oFySA4ABbZL+Py-f7SblA5yuTyVcEE5bIOpgdhQUZgAAWwHQADpWXV+KqNTJ+NoZKpkEUishMII4CINNZlEA)